# Are shared preferences in Android apps deleted when a user updates the app?

Tags: android

If I store some user settings and information in shared preferences in my android apps, and then I update the app in the Market, will those settings be erased when the app updates?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No, the Shared Preferences will remain.

Comment: This is also nothing personal, but although testing should be the ultimate endpoint to the question, it is nice for someone like me to be able to do a simple search and get a quick answer.  I only say this because as a noob, questions like this pop into my head AS I'm programming.  Now, I can move forward without worrying about said question, but one should STILL test everything.

Comment: Its a different question, but how to delete the shared preferences when application is updated or reinstalled?

Comment: It's easy, but you have to open another question for that.

Comment: I would rather google and find the answer than test an update app and check log out zzZ :p

Comment: @Cristian - small questions like these are incredibly valuable - I typed my question into google and got this post, and hence the answer to the same question in about 3 seconds.

Comment: @Louis Sayers - I agree 100% with Louis Sayers.  This post saved me 10 minutes of valuable time.  Thanks for the answer, though!

Comment: @Cristian StackOverflow saves me so much development time BECAUSE OF answers to simple questions such as this.

Comment: Another note: make sure the shared preference name is the SAME between upgrades! I had different names between versions, and so the new version isn't picking up the saved preferences from previous version... wasted an entire morning to debug this... :-(

Answer (score 1):

To make the answer simple: **NO** in normal circumstances.

> The update process only replaces the apk file(and so what is in it for
>   example drawables,...) and does not alter databases,sharedpreferences
>   and any other files that generated in run time(probably in this
>   case,new App is installed with the UID that is equal to UID of
>   previous App).

But following this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/JGquZuDK8wI) it seems that there are cases when data could be lost. Like changing Copy PROTECTION FROM ON to OFF OR OFF to ON.
Quoting the answer:

> It turns out when we posted the update copy protection was turned off,
>   but for our initial release it was turned on.  Which caused all our 
>   shared preferences to get lost, we could no longer create private data
>   files, and the game started randomly crashing.