# Android arp table - developing questions

Tags: java, android

I've got two problems with the android app I'm writing.

I'm reading out the local arp table from `/proc/net/arp` and save ip and corresponding mac address in a hash map. See my function. It's working properly.

```
    /**
     * Extract and save ip and corresponding MAC address from arp table in HashMap
     */
    public Map<String, String> createArpMap() throws IOException {      
        checkMapARP.clear();
        BufferedReader localBufferdReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/proc/net/arp")));
        String line = "";       

        while ((line = localBufferdReader.readLine()) != null) {            
            String[] ipmac = line.split("[ ]+");
            if (!ipmac[0].matches("IP")) {
                String ip = ipmac[0];
                String mac = ipmac[3];
                if (!checkMapARP.containsKey(ip)) {
                    checkMapARP.put(ip, mac);               
                }                   
            }
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(checkMapARP);
    }
```

1. First problem:

   I'm also using a broadcast receiver. When my app receives the State `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` i check if the connection to the gateway is established. If true i call my function to read the arp table. But in this stage the system has not yet builded up the arp table. Sometimes when i receive the connection state the arp table is sill empty.

   Anyone got an idea to solve this?
2. Second problem:

   I want to save the ip and mac address of the gateway in a persistent way. Right now i'm using [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for this. Maybe it's better to write to an internal storage?

   Any tips?

Comment: Second problem. Use sqlite database. SharedPreferences may get cleared when application update occurs. So better put the values in sqlite

Comment: @kumar SharedPreferences should never get cleared unless it's a bug like http://b.android.com/2066 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860823/are-shared-preferences-in-android-apps-deleted-when-a-user-updates-the-app

Comment: So it's okay to use SharedPreferences it think.

Answer (score 2):

For the first problem you could start a new thread that runs that method after sleeping for a set amount of time or until it has some entries (Make a `Runnable` with a mailbox to get the Map) - unless you need to use the map directly, then I think the only way is to wait for the entries. For example (if you need to use the map directly):

```
public Map<String, String> createArpMap() throws IOException {      
    checkMapARP.clear();
    BufferedReader localBufferdReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/proc/net/arp")));
    String line = "";       
    while ((line = localBufferdReader.readLine()) == null) {
        localBufferdReader.close();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        localBufferdReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/proc/net/arp")));
    }
    do {            
        String[] ipmac = line.split("[ ]+");
        if (!ipmac[0].matches("IP")) {
            String ip = ipmac[0];
            String mac = ipmac[3];
            if (!checkMapARP.containsKey(ip)) {
                checkMapARP.put(ip, mac);               
            }                   
        }
    } while ((line = localBufferdReader.readLine()) != null);
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(checkMapARP);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Pescis. I will test this one!