# Process command "arp -a" on android?

Tags: java, android, process, runtime

I'm trying to call "arp -a" on my android device, but since it only works for pc - how do i change this? Is there a way to access a list of the ip-addresses, that arp -a gives you, but on android instead?

My code is like this on the android device:

```
try {

        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("arp -a");
        process.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        int i = 0;
        while (reader.ready()) {
            i++;
            String ip = reader.readLine();
            if (i >= 4) {
                ip = ip.substring(2, 15) + "\n";
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13647492/3410697

You need to read "/proc/net/arp" for that

Comment: @PedroOliveira And then how do i execute the command?

Comment: You don't. There is no command for that in android. Check the answer I posted.

Comment: @PedroOliveira It doesn't work the way i want - i'd like it to print all the available network addresses including subnets, but using the method in the other post just returns something like 10.0.2.2 52:55:0a..... 
Not any list of ip's etc?

Answer (score -1):

Install busybox and some terminal emulator, connect to Wi-Fi and you are done.